# rsync by manual giving error output

Tags: debian, rsync

I would like to get a file to build an old release

```
rsync http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xmovie/xmovie_1.9.12-1.1_i386.deb debian-40r0-i386-DVD-1.iso
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

This file is downloadable via browser. I have a hard time interpreting what is wrong with my system.

Answer (score 1):

RSYNC is not designed  to download files over http. You can download using 'wget' or 'curl'.

```
wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xmovie/xmovie_1.9.12-1.1_i386.deb
```

Comment: Yep. Specifically, `rsync` uses servername:filepath to specify remote files, so `http://archive.debian.org/debian/...` will be interpreted as referring to the file "//archive.debian.org/debian/..." on the server named "http". There's no server by that name, hence the "Could not resolve hostname" error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned since I was misreading, but the example is `rsync://server.org/path/binary-i386-1.iso binary-i386-1.iso` and I attempt `rsync://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xmovie/xmovie_1.9.12-1.1_i386.deb debian-40r0-i386-DVD-1.iso` which gave, 'No such file or directory'. The link to the file is correct and the example is from https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/ but I had a blind spot already on the jigdo manual that I wonder if I still am overlooking something which would mean my rsync attempt is a faulty one..